# Access Android Accessibility.Gesture from abstract class

Tags: android, android-gesture, accessibilityservice

I am trying to perform a tap at a certain X Y part of the screen. The problem I am running into is when I call it directly from my abstract class the dispatchGesture does not trigger. How can I call it directly from the abstract class?

So far I know I can access it if I set a static variable in my abstract class, but this means a new event has to trigger instead of using the past event that triggered which is a little slow or outdated :

```
public class AutoService extends AccessibilityService {
public static boolean canDoTask = false;
public static int SX = 100;
public static int SY = 100;

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
 AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
    String packageName = Tools.getPackage(source);

  if (canDoTask){
      pressLocation(SX, SY);
   }
}

public void pressLocation(int x, int y){
    Log.e(TAG, "PRESS LOCATION : " + x +":"+ y);
    GestureDescription.Builder builder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
    Path p = new Path();
    p.moveTo(x, y);
    builder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(p, 150L, 50L));
    GestureDescription gesture = builder.build();
    dispatchGesture(gesture, new GestureResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
            super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
            Log.e(TAG, "DISPACHED");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription) {
            super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);
            Log.e(TAG, "CANCELLED");
        }
    }, null);

    Log.e(TAG, "END OF PRESS");
    canDoTask = false;
}
}
```

This is my secondary class where I want to call the method from:

```
public abstract class MyOtherClass
{
    // SOME CODE HERE TO CHECK VARIABLES



    // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL pressLocation at
    public static void processTask()
    {
         canDoTask = true;
    }
}
```

I read in a forum that someone did this by using `onServiceConnect()` but they didn't have any example code of how you would do this or exactly which methods you would take.

```
protected void onServiceConnected()
{
    super.onServiceConnected();
}
```

Comment: I would recommend asking this in a different way. Asking: "How do I call a function i don't have access to in a given class, from said class" is only going to net you answers of: "You can't". But, if you ask it in terms of what you're trying to accomplish, perhaps we can come up with something better than what you are trying, without taking stabs in the dark as to your actual intent.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `AccessibilityService` instance and invoke methods via it.

1.Create a static field of your `AccessibilityService`:

```
public class AutoService extends AccessibilityService {
    private static AutoService mAutoService; 
}
```

2.Initialize it in `onServiceConnected()`:

```
public class AutoService extends AccessibilityService {
    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        super.onServiceConnected();
        mAutoService = this;
    }

...
}
```

3.Create a method for getting the instance:

```
public class AutoService extends AccessibilityService {
    public static MyAccessibilityService getInstance(){
        return mAutoService;
    }

...

}
```

4.Now in your abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyOtherClass {
    AutoService autoService = AutoService.getInstance();
    if(autoService != null) {
        autoService.pressLocation(x, y);
    }
}
```